# stream webcam via webpage asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

H,

How do I stream my webcam through a webpage in c# using asp.net

Thanks
Sp

Comment: Depends a lot on how your webcam works.  Some webcams come with their own HTTP server software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this sponsored event happens only once, you can get a 2-week free trial from StreamZilla (http://www.streamzilla.eu/online-store/online-cdn-store) and use Flash Media Live Encoder (http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/flashmediaencoder/) to stream via their network. This will make it 100% free (assuming that you provide the webcam and a powerful PC yourself).

Other providers (eg. UStream) might have trial periods as well, or you might even get it for free if you explain them about the charity part. I've got good experiences with StreamZilla and UStream's Watershed.

Contact me if you need more help.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you want: streaming (more delay but better quality) or live view (like MSN, Skype Video, etc - less delay but lower quality).

For the first one, you need an encoder API as well as some media server to distribute the video for you. For the latter, you need Flash, Skype API, or similar API and users need direct access to (a port) on your PC.

Tell us a bit more about what you're trying to achieve. Since I've been in this business for years, I might be able to help you out if I get to understand what you want.

Comment: Im doing a sponsored event for charity and I want to set my webcam to send the stream to a webpage so people can watch, using the simplist way possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are asp.net then silverlight 4.0 is way to do this. Silverlight is application framework to develop rich internet application and this now supports all webcam api also.

Here is the link to display how you can do this.
http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-camera-and-microphone-support.aspx